# How to get rid of dotted box around pasted code in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Every time I paste some piece of code from another cs file, the editor shows a dotted box around ther pasted code. I find this is annoying and don't know how to get rid of it in a neat way or better never have it shown in the first place.

For now, I am simply copying the code-segment again from the current file and re-pasting in the current file. This gets rid of the dotted box around the code segment.

Anyone knows a better way?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your extensions? I'm not seeing this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am having VS 2010 Premium with Resharper 7. I disabled Productivity power tools extension but still the problem persists. No other extension that I have seems relevant, I'll check further.

Comment: Aha! It's the Resharper feature. The same problem is discussed in one of the posts here -> http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/437696

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by ReSharper 7. It's a a feature but apparently [it's a bit buggy](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/437696).

Quoting a user from the thread:

> I found that this problem only happens if you copy and paste code into
>   a class where the proper using namespace don't exist. If the class you
>   are copying the code into already has the proper reference usings for
>   the code being pasted then the dotted box goes away like it should.
>   This information should help the test team in duplicating the issue.
>   Another work around to the issue is go ahead and paste in the correct
>   using namespaces then paste in the code your going to be copying in
>   and you'll never get the left over dotted box otherwise you'll have to
>   do the other work around previously mentioned.